# How to automatically display a text file when pressing the button using javascript

Tags: javascript, text-files

everyone. 
I need your help.
Here is my code, it will display part of the text file when the user choose one.
However,I don't want the user to choose one file to display. 
I just want it to show **E:\data.txt** automatically when pressing a button.
How can i do this?
Thousand thanks!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function readfile(f) {

var reader = new FileReader(); 
reader.readAsText(f);
reader.onload = function() {
var text = reader.result; 
var options = text.split("\n");
var option1 = options[1]+'\n'+options[2];             
var out = document.getElementById("output");
out.innerHTML = ""; 
out.appendChild(document.createTextNode(option1)); 
}
reader.onerror = function(e) { 
console.log("Error", e); 
};
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Select the file to display:
<input type="file" onchange="readfile(this.files[0])"></input>
<pre id="output"></pre>
</body>
```

Comment: I wouldn't let you read files from my hard drive automatically, rather I consider an attempt to do that as a malicious attack...

Comment: Thank you! I want to open the file in my local disk. Is that possible?

Comment: Nope, it's not possible (to do it automatically).

Comment: Not without choosing a file from a file browser, it's a security issue, and you can't make any workarounds to achieve this.

Comment: @azhwkd: That would be a huge security issue. Can you support your claim by linking to some official resource?

Comment: @FelixKling actually you are right, i didn't give it much thought. It's not possible

Comment: I don't understand. Why does the readFile function can work? why it is not a security issue?

Comment: use ajax to load your file. as @FelixKing sayd it's not possible.

Comment: @lq1941 `FileReader` works, because user can choose the file(s) himself, or not choose files at all. If you could do this automatically, you could read any file from user's machine, and send it to a server. That's what I'd call a malicious attack...